# modern c++ for 16-bit binaries?

Tags: c++, windows, x86-16, c++17

It's a silly question, but... I have recently played with djgpp and was surprised one can compile/link modern c++17 code into 32-bit dos binaries. Mingw covers win32 and win64. But there's a gaping hole as regards win16. Are there any c++17 compilers capable of producing 16-bit code (for dos, windows or any other os)?

Comment: There is not much sense in producing such code - unless for a 16-bit processor. If you find such one still currently in use, you might find a compiler, too, supporting c++17. There are some 16-bit DSP from TI I am aware of (although cannot name one concretely), so you could try there -- no guarantee, though...

Comment: @Aconcagua check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBkNBP00wJE&t=9s

Comment: Nice to see... But that's just playing around. A C64? Played with that when being a kid thirty years ago and it was going to be superseded even then! Would be curious who still writes compilers for such outdated hardware...

Comment: @Aconcagua there's sdcc, for example, but it's C. 8-bit CPUs are still used, surprisingly.

Comment: 8-bit, there are quite a lot of micro controllers around - e. g. those using atmega chips (Arduino!). There are 16-bit [PIC](http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/16-bit) mc arround, too. Does not seem, though, as the corresponding compilers support C++17 yet (at the time writing this comment)...

Comment: @Aconcagua you can also execute 16-bit dos binaries inside a browser using the JS [port](https://js-dos.com/) of dosbox. So it's one way of providing online apps :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163428/discussion-between-aconcagua-and-user1095108).